# overriding undeclared methods in subclass

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a class with some methods neither declared in .h file nor in any category, I want to override these methods in the subclass to change the behavior slightly. I am thinking of simply redefining those methods in subclass. Is it a good idea? would it even work?

Comment: Are you saying that you wish to override private methods?

Comment: yes.. they are sort of private.. objective-c doesn't have anything called private methods i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally the subclass needs to know what the methods are if it wants to override the method and still call super.

One way of doing this is by having a separate header file which both the super class and subclass implementations both import.

```
// MyClass_protected.h

- (void)someMethodThatYouWantSubclassesToBeAbleToOverride;
```

Then

```
// MyClass.m

#import "MyClass_protected.h"

// MySubClass.m

#import "MyClass_protected.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

It'll 'work' in that the compiler allows it. The class that defines these methods probably assumes they do particular things when called, which your implementation needs to respect when overriding them to avoid introducing bugs in the use of the class's interface.

Comment: thanks.. actually the method definitions are kind of obsolete.. it doesn't take into account a lot of things. so I need to change that.

Comment: By the way is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can override private methods in a base class but the problem is that you can't call `[super someMethod]`. If you wish to completely replace the original method then this isn't an issue.

Otherwise you need to let the derived class know about the methods in the parent class.